# JAXB return 403 error after parsing stackoverflow RSS

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, rss

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(StackOverflowXPathMap.class);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

URL xmlURL = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/feeds");

URLConnection conn = xmlURL.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36");
conn.connect();

InputStream xml = xmlURL.openStream();
StackOverflowXPathMap stackOverflowXPathMap = (StackOverflowXPathMap) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
System.out.println(stackOverflowXPathMap.getAuthor());
xml.close();

Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(stackOverflowXPathMap, System.out);
```

I`m trying to parse RSS from stackowerflow, but I have some troubles.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds
I used to off my firewall and try run this code from other computer. I had the same 403